# Python Script to find lowest coordinates in a list

Tags: python, find, coordinates

I have a list containing coordinates in the order of Y,X,Z. I am trying to use python to find the coordinates for lowest Z value. The list contains 4 sets of coordinates separated by space. Part of the code I am using is below.

```
<gml:coordList>200.0001 400.0001 30.0001 210.0002 410.0002 31.0002 190.0003 401.0003 29.0003 213.0004 402.0004 38.0004</gml:coordList>


y1,x1,z1,y2,x2,z2,y3,x3,z3,y4,x4,z4 = coordList[0:-1].split(' ')

list1 = []

list1.append((z1,y1,x1))
list1.append((z2,y2,x2))
list1.append((z3,y3,x3))
list1.append((z4,y4,x4))
minz = min((list1))
x, y, z = minz[0:-1].split(' ')
```

The error I am getting is this :
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

May I know why I am getting error and if there is a better way to achieve my goal?

Thank you

Comment: You should post the full error, to make it easy for us to see where it is going wrong. However, your `min()` is returning a tuple because you have added tuples to `list1`. Why do you believe you have to `split()` this tuple again. Note: you may want to `map(float, coordList...)` because currently you are `min()`ing base on the string, which is not likely what you want.

Comment: tuples are immutable. meaning they cannot be altered. Your attempt to split is causing the error.  you may want to consider creating a class for your x,y,z coordinates.

Comment: @TimothyLombard what does the immutability of tuples have to do with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `minz` is already a tuple type, you can assign `x`,`y`,`z` to each tuple value.

```
z, y, x = minz
```

Comment: Thank you Miket25 for your help. It works and i will use your answer

Answer (score 0):

The `min` function, when used on a list of tuples, sorts the tuples by comparing all items in the tuples one by one, and won't work if you just want to sort by one of the items in a tuple. You should use the `key` argument with the z value of each tuple for the `min` function to sort the list and find the lowest value.

```
coordList = '200.0001 400.0001 30.0001 210.0002 410.0002 31.0002 190.0003 401.0003 29.0003 213.0004 402.0004 38.0004'
y1,x1,z1,y2,x2,z2,y3,x3,z3,y4,x4,z4 = map(float, coordList[0:-1].split(' '))
list1 = []
list1.append((z1,y1,x1))
list1.append((z2,y2,x2))
list1.append((z3,y3,x3))
list1.append((z4,y4,x4))
z, y, x = min(list1, key=lambda c: c[0])
print(x, y, z)
```

This outputs:

```
401.0003 190.0003 29.0003
```

Comment: Why are you slicing `coordList`? And `key` is largely unnecessary if `z` is the first element in the `tuple`, this is what `tuple` comparisons already do.

Comment: Thank you blhsing for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues with your code:

- You `split()` a `tuple` which is an error
- You are comparing strings so you will get lexical ordering not numeric ordering
- You are unnecessarily slicing your sequences which create unnecessary duplicates

To extract your data and convert to `float`s:

```
y1,x1,z1,y2,x2,z2,y3,x3,z3,y4,x4,z4 = map(float, coordList.split())
list1.append((...))
...
```

However, this isn't very general a more general approach would be to just group the `split()` into threes:

```
list1 = []
for y, x, z in zip(*[map(float, coordList.split())]*3):
    list1.append((z, y, x))
```

Note: Assumes Py3, in Py2 wrap the `map(...)` call with `iter(map(...))`.

You could keep the coords in the same order and use the `key` arg to `min()`, e.g.:

```
list1 = list(zip(*[map(float, coordList.split())]*3))
y, x, z = min(list1, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Result:

```
x, y, z   # (401.0003, 190.0003, 29.0003)
```